# Раскрывающееся меню с номерами телефона на css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой код

```
<img src="img/flag-russia.png" class="country-flag">
            <label for="country"> 
                <div class = "country-code">
                +7
                </div>
            </label>
            <p class ="select">  >  </p>
            <select class="country" id="country" name="country">
                <option>+7 Россия</option>
                <option>+380 Украина</option>
                <option>+375 Беларусь</option>
                <option>+48 Польша</option>
                <option>+976 Монголия</option>
                <option>+86 Китай</option>
            </select>
```

Хотелось бы , чтобы при нажатии на ">" (в стилях она выглядит как галочка) вылезало меню выбора номера телефона и при выборе менялась картинка флага страны и цифра в диве "country code"

Answer (score 0):

К примеру, простая функция. В качестве картинки, регулярным выражением вырезаем только цифры из `<option>` и подставляем в тег `<img src="">`

```js
$('.select').on('click', function() {
  $('.country').show();
});
$('.country').on('change', function() {
  var op = $(this),
      ans = op.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');

  $('.country-flag').attr('src', 'img/flag-' + ans + '.png');
  $('.country-code').text(ans);
  console.log(ans);
});
```

```css
.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 11px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.country {
  display: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="img/flag-russia.png" class="country-flag">
<label for="country"> 
  <div class="country-code">
  +7
  </div>
</label>
<p class ="select"> > </p>
<select class="country" id="country" name="country">
  <option>+7 Россия</option>
  <option>+380 Украина</option>
  <option>+375 Беларусь</option>
  <option>+48 Польша</option>
  <option>+976 Монголия</option>
  <option>+86 Китай</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо,но как сделать, чтобы после выбора кода меню select полностью скрывалось до той же галочки и при нажатии на галочку сразу раскрывалось?

Comment: @PerfectELK После `$('.country-code').text(ans);` прописать вот это: `$('.country').hide();`. И убери `console.log(ans);`, он без надобности